# POST method from input HTML to spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, forms, post

Could You help me with POST method in my HTML? Okay so I have a localhost:8080/create-your-package with form and text inputs with labels. I have too a second endpoint on localhost:8080/create-package and this endpoint takes as argument Object of My type Package(all the variables that my form have). How can I take those values from input and create from them a new Object of Package and send it as POST method into create-package?

my Package

```
package com.courier.application.model;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.*;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "packages")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Package {
    @Id
    private ObjectId packageId;
    @Valid
    private Point startingPoint;
    @Valid
    private Point destinationPoint;
    private String expectedShippingTime;
    private String trackingCode;
}
```

Point Object from Package Class

```
package com.courier.application.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Point {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 25)
    private String city;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 25)
    private String street;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 7)
    private String apartment;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 7)
    private String postalCode;
}
```

my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/package-create.css">
    <title>PaczkaTrack - stwórz paczkę</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Formularz paczki</h1>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/create-package" method="POST">
    <h2>Nadawca</h2>
    <label for="startingPoint.city">Miasto</label>
    <input type="text" id="startingPoint.city" name="startingPoint.city" required>

    <label for="startingPoint.street">Ulica</label>
    <input type="text" id="startingPoint.street" name="startingPoint.street" required>

    <label for="startingPoint.apartment">Apartment</label>
    <input type="text" id="startingPoint.apartment" name="startingPoint.apartment" required>

    <label for="startingPoint.postalCode">Kod</label>
    <input type="text" id="startingPoint.postalCode" name="startingPoint.postalCode" required>

    <h2>Odbiorca</h2>

    <label for="destinationPoint.city">Miasto</label>
    <input type="text" id="destinationPoint.city" name="destinationPoint.city" required>

    <label for="destinationPoint.street">Ulica</label>
    <input type="text" id="destinationPoint.street" name="destinationPoint.street" required>

    <label for="destinationPoint.apartment">Apartment</label>
    <input type="text" id="destinationPoint.apartment" name="destinationPoint.apartment" required>

    <label for="destinationPoint.postalCode">Kod</label>
    <input type="text" id="destinationPoint.postalCode" name="destinationPoint.postalCode" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj pake!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my Controller with create-package

```
package com.courier.application.controller;

import com.courier.application.error.PackageNotFoundException;
import com.courier.application.error.PackageSentToWrongAddressException;
import com.courier.application.model.Package;
import com.courier.application.service.PackageService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@Validated
public class PackageController {

    @Autowired
    PackageService packageService;

    @GetMapping("/find-package")
    public Optional<Package> findPackageByTrackingCode(String trackingCode) throws PackageNotFoundException {
        return packageService.findByTrackingCode(trackingCode);
    }

    @PostMapping("/create-package")
    public Package createPackage(@Valid @RequestBody Package createdPackage) throws PackageSentToWrongAddressException {
        return packageService.saveCreatedPackage(createdPackage);
    }
}
```

I tried some scripts in js but none of them worked. How Can I solve my problem?

Comment: "I tried some scripts in js" You mean Java I think, not JavaScript. You wouldn't be handling a POST request in JavaScript unless you were using node.js

Comment: I guess I already solved it by <script>. Right now I have second problem I don`t know how to display info on html from JSON. Do You maybe know how to solve it?

Comment: If you've solved your problem you should either post your answer (if you think it might be helpful for others) or delete your question. After that, you can post your new question on SO, however a problem like "I don't know how to display info on html from JSON" is very broad and may not be received very well.

Comment: You should use Javascript to solve your problem even to display JSON into Html. Follow that link to learn about DOM manipulation:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: @Kenany thanks for answer. I will check this link